# How to position my element relatively to a header with CSS

Tags: css, wordpress, position, absolute, elementor

So I'm kind of a newbie when it comes to coding, and I've been trying all day to position my elementor-post__badge element on top of a header text. The catch is that I want this positioning to be relative to the header so the position will be the same across all mobile devices. How can I do that? I tried the following code but it didn't work and the position of the badge element is different from one device to another:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767.98px) {
  #parent {
    position: relative;
  }

  .elementor-post__badge {
    position: absolute;
    top: 178px !important;
    left: -14px;
    font-size: 12px !important;
  }
}
```

[image]

This is what I'm trying to achieve with the "News" badge on top of the header, but it doesn't work on all devices

Comment: please add jsfiddle of your code!

Comment: No @mkafiyan, please use always snippet tools `<>`

Comment: @SimoneRossainin yes I agree :D

Answer (score 0):

Try using other units of measurement, meant for percentages of page width and height such as, `vw`,`vh`, and `em`, instead of `px`. The change in viewer width/height is what causes inconsistencies in alignment for certain elements across browsers and devices.

https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/units.en.html